# Update all EmbeddedDocuments in EmbeddedDocumentListField if it matches criteria

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using `mongoengine` with a `Document` having a `EmbeddedDocumentListField` attribute.

```
class Child(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    value = mongoengine.IntField(required=True)
    child_type = mongoengine.StringField(required=True, choices=["type1", "type2", "type3"], unique_with=["version"])
    version = mongoengine.StringField(required=True, choices=["old", "current", "new"])


class Parent(mongoengine.Document):
    children = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Child)
```

And I'm populating my database this way:

```
def populate():
    # for each child_type
    for child_type in ["type1", "type2", "type3"]:
        for parent_id, value in compute_stuff(child_type):
            # create a new Child embedded document with version "new" and append it to the corresponding Parent                
            parent = Parent.get(parent_id)
            child = Child(value=value, child_type=child_type, version="new")
            parent.children.append(child)
            parent.save()

        update_versions(child_type)
```

Now, what I'm struggling with is my `update_versions` function. Basically, I want to update every `Child` document with the current `child_type` and version "current", and change it to version "old". And after that, do the same by changing `Child` with version "new" to version "current".

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def update_versions(child_type):
    # update "current" to "old"        
    Parent.objects(
        children__version="current",
        children__child_type=child_type
    ).update(set__children__S__version="old")
    # update "new" to "current"
    Parent.objects(
        children__version="new",
        children__child_type=child_type
    ).update(set__children__S__version="current")
```

Unfortunately, the update is not done properly, as the filter on `child_type` I'm trying to make doesn't seem to be done. This is the result I got in my database:

```
> // 1. before first populating -> OK
> db.parent.find({"_id": 1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "children" : [ ]
}
> // 2. after first populating of type1 -> OK
> db.parent.find({"_id": 1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "child_type": "type1",
            "version": "new"
        }
    ]
}
> // 3. after updating versions -> OK
> db.parent.find({"_id": 1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "child_type": "type1",
            "version": "current"  // <- this is OK
        }
    ]
}
> // 4. after first populating of type2 -> OK
> db.parent.find({"_id": 1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "child_type": "type1",
            "version": "current"  // <- this is OK
        },
        {
            "value" : 17,
            "child_type": "type2",
            "version": "new"  // <- this is OK
        }
    ]
}
> // 5. after updating versions (only "current" to "old") -> NOT OK
> db.parent.find({"_id": 1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "child_type": "type1",
            "version": "old"  // <- this is NOT OK, expecting to stay "current"
        },
        {
            "value" : 17,
            "child_type": "type2",
            "version": "new"  // <- this is OK
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Edit: This query seems to do what I want, but this is a raw Mongo query, I'd like to "translate it" to use it with mongoengine:

```
db.parent.updateMany(
    {"children.child_type": "type1", "children.version": "current"},
    {"$set": {"children.$[element].version": "old"}},
    {arrayFilters: [{"element.child_type": "type1", "element.version": "current"}]}
)
```

NB: I don't think this is a duplicate, as most questions I've found are about updating a specific EmbeddedDocument, given its id. Here I want to update every EmbeddedDocument, without filtering at all on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient solution than the one I suggested earlier is to run a raw query by getting the `Parent`'s linked [`collection`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) object:

```
def update_versions(child_type):

    def _update_from_to(current_version, new_version):
        Parent._get_collection().update_many(
            filter={
                "children.child_type": child_type,
                "children.version": current_version
            },
            update={
                "$set": {"children.$[element].version": new_version}
            },
            array_filters=[{
                "element.child_type": child_type,
                "element.version": current_version
            }],
            upsert=False
        )

    _update_from_to("current", "old")
    _update_from_to("new", "current")
```

This is way quicker to execute than updating each `Child` instance one by one!
The counterpart is that I'm using the non-documented `_get_collection` method, although it [might be made public](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1182) one day.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a way to make it work with a single query, so I did it by updating each `Child` instance one by one:

```
def update_versions(child_type):

    def _update_from_to(current_version, new_version):
        # find all the Parents with a matching Child
        parents_to_update = Parent.objects(
            children__version=current_version,
            children__child_type=child_type
        )
        for parent in parents_to_update:
            # find the matching Child in the children list
            for child in parent.children:
                if (child.version == current_version and
                        child.child_type == child_type):
                    # and update it
                    child.version = new_version
                    break
            # each parent is updated one by one, this is not efficient...
            parent.save()

    _update_from_to("current", "old")
    _update_from_to("new", "current")
```

Edit: see my other answer for a more efficient (but kinda hacky) solution